# Return sum of array elements and other fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given the following example dataset:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    prices: [1,2,3],
    category: 'stuff'
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    prices: [4,5,6],
    category: 'stuff'
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    prices: [7,8,9],
    category: 'misc'
  }
];
```

How do I get back data that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    prices: 6,
    category: 'stuff'
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    prices: 15,
    category: 'stuff'
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    prices: 24,
    category: 'misc'
  }
]
```

I can get this:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    prices: 6
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    prices: 15
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    prices: 24
  }
]
```

By using something like this:

```
[
  { $unwind: '$prices' },
  { $group: { _id: '$_id', prices: { $sum: '$prices' } } },
  { $project: { prices: 1 } }
]
```

But I can't figure out how to get it to include "category".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal way to do this is MongoDB 3.2 or newer using the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) accumulator operator in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "price": { "$sum": "$prices" }, 
        "category": "$category" 
    }}
])
```

which produces:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "category" : "stuff", "price" : 6 }
{ "_id" : 2, "category" : "stuff", "price" : 15 }
{ "_id" : 3, "category" : "misc", "price" : 24 }
```

In MongoDB version <= 3.0 you need to use the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([  
    { $unwind: '$prices' },   
    { $group: { 
        _id: '$_id', 
        prices: { $sum: '$prices' }, 
        category: { '$first': '$category' } 
    }} 
])
```